# accEvent Watcher : one event in Windows XP?

Tags: windows, sdk, automation, windows-xp

I am currently developping an app which uses the UI Automation framework to fill in forms and submit, in a web environment (IE & Chrome).

My app works in .NET 4.0 and  I am currently testing it in different contexts, such as various OS, different versions of IE, etc...

Everything seems to work seamlessly except on Chrome in Windows XP (I am testing on a virtual machine).
I have installed :

- SP3
- .NET 4.0
- UI Automation package : http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=13821

IE works absolutely fine but Chrome doesn't. After careful inspection, it seems that one of the events I am listening to (property change on an automation element) doesn't fire for Chrome (but does for IE !).

Therefore, I have installed Windows SDK 7.1 to use accEvent Watcher to check UI Automation events.
However, the list of events only contain one : "RuntimeId FocusChanged" (whereas on my personal desktop [Windows 8.1], I have all sorts of events, including name, Control Type, etc...).

Any ideas into what I should look into ? I am developping my app in VS 2010 C# Express.

Thank you in advance !